# Issue with starting node pm2 process manager in aws elastic beanstalk, npm update check failed

Tags: node.js, typescript, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, pm2

I am trying to use pm2 for process management of my typescript node application, which has been deployed to elasticbeanstalk.

Every time the pm2 launches a new instance I get this in the logs

---------------------node.js logs----------------------------

`pm2 start pm2.yaml`

`[PM2] Spawning PM2 daemon with pm2_home=/tmp/.pm2`
`[PM2] PM2 Successfully daemonized`
`[PM2][WARN] Applications server not running, starting...`
`[PM2] App [server] launched (1 instances)`

`Use pm2 show <id|name> to get more details about an app`

`npm update check failed`
`Try running with sudo or get access`
`to the local update config store via`
`sudo chown -R $USER:$(id -gn $USER) /tmp/.config`

------------------------end-----------------------

Everytime it then tries to restart the app and launch another instance, eventually ending with the degradation of the app.

I have tried to use the command that it suggest but to no avail.

any help will be massively appreciated. :)

Comment: Did you find a solution? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I encountered the same issue. The solution is to add permissions to the Elastic Beanstalk `nodejs` user, in order for it to access `/tmp/.config`. You can do so by asking Elastic Beanstalk to run the following ebextensions post deploy shell script:

`.ebextensions/00_set_npm_permissions.config`

```
files:
  "/opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/post/00_set_tmp_permissions.sh":
    mode: "000755"
    owner: root
    group: root
    content: |
      #!/usr/bin/env bash
      chown -R nodejs:nodejs /tmp/.config
```

I hope this helps.